# Database design for physics hardware

Tags: database, hardware, sqlite, physics

I have to develop a database for a unique environment. I don't have experience with database design and could use everybody's wisdom.

My group is designing a database for piece of physics hardware and a data acquisition system. We need a system that will store all the hardware configuration parameters, and track the changes to these parameters as they are changed by the user.

The setup:

- We have nearly 200 detectors and roughly 40 parameters associated with each detector. Of these 40 parameters, we expect only a few to change during the course of the experiment. Most parameters associated with a single detector are static.
- We collect data for this experiment in timed runs. During these runs, the parameters loaded into the hardware must not change, although we should be able to edit the database at any time to prepare for the next run. The current plan:

  - The database will provide the difference between the current parameters and the parameters used during last run.
  - At the start of a new run, the most recent database changes be loaded into hardware.
  - The settings used for the upcoming run must be tagged with a run number and the current date and time. This is essential. I need a run-by-run history of the experimental setup.
- There will be several different clients that both read and write to the database. Although changes to the database will be infrequent, I cannot guarantee that the changes won't happen concurrently.
- Must be robust and non-corruptible. The configuration of the experimental system depends on the hardware. Any breakdown of the database would prevent data acquisition, and our time is expensive. Database backups?

My current plan is to implement the above requirements using a sqlite database, although I am unsure if it can support all my requirements. Is there any other technology I should look into? Has anybody done something similar? I am willing to learn any technology, as long as it's mature.

Tips and advice are welcome.

Thank you,

Sean

---

**Update 1**:

*Database access*:

There are three lite applications that can write and read to the database and one application that can only read.

The applications with write access are responsible for setting a non-overlapping subset of the hardware parameters. To be specific, we have one application (of which there may be multiple copies) which sets the high voltage, one application which sets the remainder of the hardware parameters which may change during the experiment, and one GUI which sets the remainder of the parameters which are nearly static and are only essential for the proper reconstruction of the data.

The program with read access only is our data analysis software. It needs access to nearly all of the parameters in the database to properly format the incoming data into something we can analyze properly. The number of connections to the database should be >10.

*Backups*:

Another setup at our lab dumps an xml file every run. Even though I don't think xml is appropriate, I was planning to back up the system every run, just in case.

Comment: How often do you run the experiments? Is it on the scale of a few times per seconds, one time per few minutes, or just several times a day? And how often do you change the parameters? Every run, or every 1000 runs, or? These can affect the size of your database, and thus the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic things about the design; you should make sure that you don't delete data from any tables; keep track of the most recent data (probably best with most recent updated datetime); when the data value changes, though, don't delete the old data.  When a run is initiated, tag every table used with the Run ID (in another column); this way, you maintain full historical record about every setting, and can pin exactly what the state used at a given run was.

Answer (score 1):

Ask around of your colleagues.

You don't say what kind of physics you're doing, or how big the working group is, but in my discipline (particle physics) there is a deep repository of experience putting up and running just this type of systems (we call it "slow controls" and similar). There is a pretty good chance that someone you work with has either done this or knows someone who has. There may be a detailed description of the last time out in someone's thesis.

I don't personally have much to do with this, but I do know this: one common feature is to have no-delete-no-overwrite design. You can only *add* data, never remove it. This preserves your chances of figuring out what *really happened* in the case of trouble

---

Perhaps I should explain a little more. While this is an important task and has to be done right, it is not really related to physics, so you can't look it up on [Spires](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/hep/) or on [arXive.org](http://arxiv.org/). No one writes papers on the design and implementation of medium sized slow controls databases. But they do sometimes put it in their dissertations. The easiest way to find a pointer really is to ask a bunch of people around the lab.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm in nuclear physics. I have done a mild literature search, and indeed most of the info available was from the high energy community. The problem I ran into, was a problem of scale. The complexity of our device, and the community that supports is 1-2 orders of magnitude less that the army that surrounds many of the high energy devices. If you need further clarification, I can provide it.

Comment: I'm not part of the high energy community either. Look instead for work from JLAB, SLAC, underground neutrino experiments, and other smallish and medium sized projects. Much more like your scale.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly large database by the sounds of things.  So you might be able to get away with using [Oracle's free database](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html) which will give you all kinds of great flexibility with journaling (not sure if that is an actual word) and administration.

Your mentioning of 'non-corruptible' right after you say "There will be several different clients that both read and write to the database" raises a red flag for me.  Are you planning on creating some sort of application that has a interface for this?  Or were you planning on direct access to the db via a tool like TOAD?

In order to preserve your data integrity you will need to get really strict on your permissions.  I would only allow one (and a backup) person to have admin rights with the ability to do the data manipulation outside the GUI (which will make your life easier).

Backups?  Yes, absolutely!  Not only should you do daily, weekly and monthly backups you should do full and incremental.  Also, test your backup images often to confirm they are in fact working.

As for the data structure I would need much greater detail in what you are trying to store and how you would access it.  But from what you have put here I would say you need the following tables (to begin with):

```
Detectors
Parameters
Detector_Parameters
```

Some additional notes:

Since you will be doing so many changes I recommend using a version control like [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) to keep track of all your DDLs etc.  I would also recommend using something like [bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) for bug tracking (if needed) and using [google docs](http://docs.google.com) for team document management.

Hope that helps.